# Trouble getting absolute path and opening file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, file, path, filereader

I'm trying to open up a file in Android Studio. I created an asset folder that has the path:

```
app_name\app\src\main\assets\file.csv
```

When I try to open it using

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("assets/PlayerDB.csv");
```

I get an error that file is not found. To try and figure out the location of the root directory for getting files, I used the following:

```
File f = new File("test/test.txt");
String Path = f.getAbsolutePath();
Log.v("File Path",Path);
```

However, this just prints "test/test.txt" to the log. Any ideas on how to get absolute path to work & how to open the file from the assets folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Assets are not files at runtime, so there is no File path to be obtained for them.

Answer (score 1):

Place your PlayerDB.csv file in the /assets directory under the Android project. Use AssetManager class to access it.

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("PlayerDB.csv");
```

And if your using it in a fragment

```
AssetManager am = getActivity().getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("PlayerDB.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply as

```
getAssets().open("file.csv");
```

Comment: I get a "cannot resolve symbol getAssets" error when I try this. Any ideas?

Comment: getAssets() is a method on Context. If you are calling this in a fragment, try getActivity().getAssets().open("file.csv").

Comment: this is still giving me errors:

'FileReader file = getActivity().getAssets().open("PlayerDB.csv");'

"unhandled exception java.io.ioexception"

Comment: Catch the exception to find out the cause.  try {...} catch (Exception e) { Log.d("FOOBAR", e.toString() };